# uitextfield in swift 3 not saving

Tags: ios, swift, save, uitextfield, swift3

My textfield is not saving. My code is listed below. Thanks

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var textext: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
@IBAction func savesavesave(_ sender: Any) {
    let myText = textext.text
    UserDefaults.standard.set(myText, forKey: "myKey")

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34803102/2303865

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize the user defaults with its method and test if working
I'm writing from my memory:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(myText, forKey: "myKey")

UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

**EDIT**
from [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UserDefaults/Listings/Controller_m.html)

> // Note that we don't synchronize with the file system or anything; this will happen
>   **when the app quits**. There are times when an **explicit synchronize might be necessary**,
>   but often it's not. Synchronizing unecessarily can also be a performance issue.

According apple docs I understands (you may think otherwise) that if you want to get the value during runtime, and not saving it in your variable - you should sync manually

**EDIT AGAIN**
Thanks to @LeoDabus I understand that maybe it's available during runtime too. So don't count my answer

Comment: No need to force synchronize

Comment: I believe it's best practice to force it, in all examples and tutorials it's like that... Unless something changed and I don't know...

Comment: show me one from apple where they do it. btw I did not down vote it

Comment: @LeoDabus there you go, I've edited my answer and added from Apple, good luck!

Comment: This is exactly what I said. Not needed in most situation.

Comment: But it will only be saved when app quits, so how do you expect to save it? I think you should keep your property in your classes and load from UserDefaults only when app starts... I think that's the best practice for you, otherwise it just won't be saved for use during runtime.

Comment: during runtime it is available in memory right away, even it it has not been written to disk. I have never seen a situation where forcing sync is necessary. BTW where is the tutorial?

Comment: Now I saw your answer (in the link) and I understand his problem... I wanted him to comment what helped him.. Thanks for the explanations..

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your textfield is not being first responder. For example, you may call the below code before saving:

```
@IBAction func savesavesave(_ sender: Any) {
    textext.resignFirstResponder()
    let myText = textext.text
    UserDefaults.standard.set(myText, forKey: "myKey")
}
```

Comment: how can i get the text to save? When I change view controllers all of the data is erased.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this for saving textfield into UserDefaults:

```
let myText = TextFiled1.text
UserDefaults.standard.set(myText, forKey: "myKey")
```

If you want to get that textfield value then write this:

```
let value = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "myKey")
print(value!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is not necessary synchronize happens, if app is about to exit. For accessing the information during app launches it is necessary that the synchronization happens. For more info you can check: [iOS NSUserDefaults access before synchronize completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183183/ios-nsuserdefaults-access-before-synchronize-completion)